# How do I use loadPath with sass-loader and webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass, webpack-dev-server, sass-loader, dart-sass

I'm creating a little app that is bundled with `webpack`. I'm using `sass` in the project and all `scss` files are located in a `scss` located in the root directory. I've got some partials I've created in a directory named `partials`. The directory structure looks like this:

[directory structure of quiz app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XanB.png)

At the top of the `quiz.module.scss` file, I have this:

```scss
@use "colors" as *;
@use "font";
```

I didn't want to write `@use "partials/colors"` and `@use "partials/font"`, so I decided to include `scss/partials` in the list of `loadPaths` used by `scss`. I have this somewhere in my `webpack.dev.js` file:

```js
const PATHS_TO_SASS_PARTIALS = ["scss/partials"]
```

and this somewhere else:

```js
{
  test: /\.module\.scss$/,
  use: [
    {
      loader: "style-loader"
    },
    {
      loader: "css-loader",
      options: {
        modules: {
          mode: "local"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      loader: "resolve-url-loader"
    },
    {
      loader: "sass-loader",
      options: {
        sourceMap: true,
        sassOptions: {
          loadPaths: PATHS_TO_SASS_PARTIALS
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I think this should point `webpack` to load the `_colors.scss` file when I write `@use "colors" as *;` in a file like `quiz.module.scss`, but it isn't working. I get the following error when I run `webpack-dev-server`:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "colors" as *;
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  scss\quiz.module.scss 1:1  root stylesheet
```

Am I doing something wrong or the `loadPaths` option doesn't work with `sass-loader`? I don't want to have to write `@use "partials/colors"`. I was expecting that the `loadPaths` option will be passed by `sass-loader` to `sass` and the `@use` will work directly as mentioned above.

I read somewhere that sass load paths are evaluated relative to the path from which `sass` is called. That may be a reason for the error. I'm not sure. I'll just assume that since I'm starting `webpack-dev-server` from the root of the project on the command line, both `sass-loader` and `sass` would also be called from the same place.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The `includePaths` option is the correct one to use with `sass-loader`. This option allows you to specify directories for the loader to resolve `@import` declarations. Here's how you can use it:

```js
{
    loader: 'sass-loader',
    options: {
        sassOptions: {
            includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, 'Develop', 'Styles')]
        }
    }
}
```

In this configuration, `sass-loader` will look in the `Develop/Styles` directory (relative to the directory of your `webpack.config.js` file) to resolve `@import` declarations in your Sass/SCSS files.